# How to add json.net to Xamarin Forms, on the native projects or on the PCL?

Tags: json.net, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I'm developing an App with Xamarin Forms, I need to add json.net to the project from Nugat (I think) do I need to do it on every native project or can I do it on the PCL project

Thanks Shimon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just need to add it to your core PCL project.

Comment: Sorry for the question but i'm now to Xamarin, how do i do it on Xamarin studio on Mac?

Comment: @ShimonWiener - In the Solution window double click the Packages folder in the PCL project to open the Add Packages dialog (or right click the project and select Add - Add NuGet packages) then find Json.NET (Newtonsoft.Json) and install it by clicking Add Package.